# How to purge unmanaged hosts entries when hosts file has non-standard location?

Tags: puppet, hosts

I am using resource host. During my experiments the resource type "resources" has no impacts if a host resource is using a non-standard target.

```
resources { 'host':
  purge => true,
}

host { 'localhost.localdomain':
  ip           => '127.0.0.1',
  target       => '/chroot/etc/hosts',
}
```

When I am using target /etc/hosts and I remove the host resource or rename it the output is:

```
Info: Applying configuration version '1560267493'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Profile:abc:Hosts/Host[localhost.localdomain]/ensure: removed
Info: Computing checksum on file /etc/hosts
Notice: /Stage[main]/Profile::abc:Hosts/Host[localhost.localdomain]/ensure: created
```

When I am using non standard target e.g. /chroot/etc/hosts nothing happens. (If I rename the entry then just another host entry is created)

Another strange behaviour is that when there is no /etc/hosts file on the agent node an error is thrown: (even if I am using a different target.)
Error: Could not find a suitable provider for host

Versions: Puppetserver: 5.3.8, puppet agent: 4.10.8

Answer (score 1):

> I am using resource host. During my experiments the resource type "resources" has no impacts if a host resource is using a non-standard target.

That is not surprising.  The `resources` resource type can purge only resource instances that the specified resource type "prefetches".  For the `Host` resource type, this is hosts recorded in the default hosts file.  This is the reason for the documented limitation that a `Resources` cannot purge type `ssh_authorized_key`.  For that, as for hosts in other target files, Puppet has no way to identify the resources you want to purge.

> Another strange behaviour is that when there is no /etc/hosts file on
>   the agent node an error is thrown: (even if I am using a different
>   target.) Error: Could not find a suitable provider for host

I would account that a bug.  You could consider [filing a ticket](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com).